# What is the correct way to write a fractional number in a formal letter?

Tags: style, business-writing, time-depiction, cover-letter, numerals

If I'm talking about a length of time in a cover letter, let's say 5.5 years, what would be the correct way to write this?

- five-and-a-half years
- 5-1/2 years
- 5.5 years

Comment: When using a fraction introduces problems with how the text will look or sound, change the unit of measurement. _66 months_ avoids the issues of hyphens (or not) and the solidus when precision is required and _more than 5 years_ will suffice in many cases.

Answer (score 9):

> five and a half years

No hyphens. Hyphens are for adjective phrases:

> It was a five-and-a-half-year journey.

You also don't use the hyphen with the fraction.

> 5<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> years

Comment: ...unless you're using the Chicago or AP style guides, which specify usages like one-quarter and (Chicago only, I think) five and one-half. (One of my clients is a non-profit that uses AP supplemented by an internal style sheet.)

Comment: Eh, okay. Those grate on my eyes, but you're citing official sources.

Comment: True, but I'm just citing this for completeness's sake. For a cover letter to accompany a resume, Chicago/AP is unlikely to apply. @bernk, if that's what this is, just pick a method and stick to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my copy of the Franklin Covey style guide agrees with this, although it's not the most recent edition. Even the Yahoo! style guide requires you write one-quarter, although it (interestingly) absolutely refuses to provide a ruling on how to write out numbers like "1 1/2". But in dialog or quoted speech, such as "five and a half" - none of these references offer guidance.

Comment: I'd write "five and one half" rather than "five and a half" in formal writing, unless I was quoting someone. Just like I'd write "five and two thirds" rather than "five and a couple of thirds". Also, I think the big-numbers rule applies: Past 20 or so we switch from spelling out to use hindu-arabic digits. I'd do similarly at some point with fractions. Like, "12 34/137" rather than "twelve and thirty-four one hundred thirty-sevenths".

Comment: @Jay But you can have *one* third vs. *two* thirds. You can only have *a* half or you have a whole. "Five and one half" sounds pompous. Also, AP style is to use numerals above 10, not 20.

Comment: FWIW, MLA Handbook says to spell out numbers that can be written in one or two words and to use numerals for others. With various special cases that I won't go into. I was taught in school to use numerals above 20, but I don't recall if that came from some recognized style guide or where.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Personally I think "a half" sounds sloppy. (shrug) Not something I'd fight to the death over.

Comment: @Jay Yeah, I wouldn't get in the steel cage over it either. Neither is wrong.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum But if you want to travel to Michigan for a death match, let me know where to meet you.

Comment: @Jay I'm not stepping into a steel-cage death math for anything less than "the fight to ban *impactive*, *impactful*, and the use of *impact* as a verb when not applied to meteorites."